# How to set image size using GD::Barcode

Tags: perl, gd, barcode

I am using GD::Barcode to generate barcodes of course, but did not find a way to set the image width.
How do I do that?
Here is what I am doing in my (Mojolicious) application:

```
  #action that generates an image/png barcode which is embedded in the html
  use GD::Barcode::EAN8;
  use Time::Seconds
  sub barcode {
        my ($c) = @_;
        my $barcode_id = $c->stash('barcode_id');
        $c->app->log->debug('Generating barcode:' . $barcode_id);
        my $img_data = GD::Barcode::EAN8->new($barcode_id)->plot->png;

        $c->res->headers->content_type('image/png');
        $c->res->headers->header(
            'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=' . ONE_MONTH . ', must-revalidate, private');
        $c->render_data($img_data);

  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Note: Yes it is easy to just change the image size in the tag 

    <img  src="/barcode/<%=$barcode%>" width="123" />
but this is not wath I want. Mainly because Chrome tends to antialias the "zoomed" images.

Comment: Can you post the solution down in the answers section so we can get this off the Unanswered list?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

## Solved!!!

I just needed to realize that

```
GD::Barcode::EAN8->new($barcode_id)->plot;
```

returns a GD::Image instance.

Thanks to Sherzod B. Ruzmetov who wrote Image::Resize.

and here is the new solution:

---

```
use Time::Seconds
#...
#generate an image/png barcode which is embedded in the html
require Image::Resize ;
GD::Image->trueColor( 0 );#turn it off since Image::Resize turned it on
require GD::Barcode::EAN8;

sub barcode {
    my ($c) = @_;
    my $barcode_id = $c->stash('barcode_id');
    $c->app->log->debug('Generating barcode:' . $barcode_id);
    my $img = GD::Barcode::EAN8->new($barcode_id)->plot();
    my $img_data = Image::Resize->new($img)->resize(100, 80,1)->png;
    $c->res->headers->content_type('image/png');
    $c->res->headers->header(
        'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=' . ONE_MONTH . ', must-revalidate, private');
    $c->render_data($img_data);

}
```

Hope this helps someone else.